# RedisError ConnectionTimeoutError: Connection timeout

Tags: redis, vercel, connection-timeout

Getting error at Vercel

```
RedisError ConnectionTimeoutError: Connection timeout
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/socket.js:177:124)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:631:28)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:517:28)
    at Socket._onTimeout (node:net:598:8)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)
No exports found in module "../../dist/server.js".
Did you forget to export a function or a server?
INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 10009.42 ms  Phase: init Status: timeout
RedisError ConnectionTimeoutError: Connection timeout
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/socket.js:177:124)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:631:28)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:517:28)
    at Socket._onTimeout (node:net:598:8)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)
No exports found in module "../../dist/server.js".
Did you forget to export a function or a server?
INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 10010.40 ms  Phase: invoke   Status: error   Error Type: Runtime.Unknown
```

At local it is working fine. The same code was deployed at the vercel and was working fine but today getting an error at vercel.

At local it takes more than 10 seconds to connect with redis. My Redis database it deployed at https://app.redislabs.com/

Also can suggest free redis database hosting for personal use / learning.